# MPEG to AVI library

Tags: media, converters, mpeg, avi

I am searching for a library that can convert MPEG to AVI.

Is there a good one for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

(My program is written in VC++, Thanks)

(I am using DirectShow.But I don't know how to use it to convert MPEG to AVI ? I know how to build graph and render video that already has an appropriate codec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the prog language you're working with so I will just mention ffmpeg.
http://ffmpeg.org/

Answer (score 1):

[libavcodec](http://ffmpeg.org/) is very popular.

Answer (score 0):

Your best best is to use a audio/video framework.

I would recommend the following:

### Windows

- [DirectShow SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Media Foundation SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms696274(VS.85).aspx)
- [Quicktime SDK](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/download/)

### Mac

- [QTKit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/qtkit.html)

### Linux

- [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org)

If you need a cross platform solution I would recommend the commercial [MainConcept CodecSDK](http://www.mainconcept.com), which has some of the best video codec implementations around.